# Using today's date as my condition how do I write a formula to reference a rolling cell tied to today's date?

Tags: excel-2010

I have an amortization table.  I want to write a formula that will tell me the principal balance the month prior to today's date.  For example, today is 10/16/2013, I want the formula to tell me the principal balance on 10/1/2013 and pull it from my amortization table.

Answer (score 1):

for the examples, the date you want to manipulate is assumed to be in A1.

For the start of the month: `=Date(Year(A1),Month(A1),1)`
For the end of the month: `=EOMonth(A1,0)`

You can then use that date in lookups:
e.g. if your amortization table is on Sheet2, with your dates in column A, and your principal in column B, you could use `=VLOOKUP(Date(Year(A1),Month(A1),1),Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)` to get the principal on the 1st of the month

Comment: wow thank you and almost. =VLOOKUP(Date(Year(A1),Month(A1),1),Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)  got me the date on 9/1/2013 and I am looking for it on 10/1/2013.  I tried substituting =EOMonth(A1,0) for =Date(Year(A1),Month(A1),1) but get an error

Comment: if you want the following month, then `=Date(Year(A1),Month(A1)+1,1)` should work